# Use of -> in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm used to create properties for pretty much everything. Probably too much, given. I also use instance variables, but I don't reference them with `self->myvar` but rather just `myvar`.

I recently was exposed to a code using a lot of `self->` where I would have used a property. When I said one of the reasons I use `@property` (retain) is because I don't want to have to explicitly retain my object, I was told that I am "lazy". It's probably true, but it's also that I want to avoid bugs where I would have forgotten to retain.

Anyways, generally, what do you guys think about `->` in Cocoa code?

Comment: "I recently was exposed to a code using a lot of "self->"... turn around... run away!!!!

Answer (score 6):

Laziness is a virtue.

I use `->` in `copyWithZone:`, to access the copy's instance variables. (I don't use property accessors here for the same reasons I don't use them in `init` or `dealloc` — they may trigger side effects that would be bad in the half-initialized copy.) I also use `self->` in this context because I like the way that reads:

```
other->foo = [self->foo copy];
other->bar = [self->bar copy];
other->baz = self->baz; //Non-object or object not owned (may be omitted entirely in the latter case)
```

I can't think of another context in which I use `->` on objects.

Answer (score 1):

IMO there's not much value in using -> over plain ivar access. Sometimes it's useful for debugging purposes if you wanna access a different object's ivars. If it's just about differentiating ivars from local vars, you can use one of the established naming schemes (don't go into detail here) just as well.

The use of properties is a whole different story. IMO in most cases one should prefer using properties than plain ivars. Automatic retain is one reason, a good abstraction another.

Answer (score 1):

For the majority of stuff you do, don't use `->` unless you're writing C or C++ Code with Objective-C.  It is easier for you, the compiler, and memory management if you create properties and reference them appropriately.

```
@interface MYObject : NSObject {
@public // don't use this, please!
    MYOtherObject *obj;
}

@property (retain) MYOtherObject *obj;

@end

@implementation MYObject

@synthesize obj;

@end


// later in your code

MYObject *thing = [[MYObject alloc] init];
MYOtherObject *other;

// Good
other = [thing obj];
other = thing.obj;
other = [thing valueForKey:@"obj"]; // I hope my KVC is correct here.  :(

// Bad, and soon to be deprecated I believe. (all members are @protected unless you use @public)
other = thing->obj;
```

Why is it bad?  You can declare members in the implementation file like this:  (64-bit and iPhone)

```
@interface MYObject : NSObject

@property (retain) MYOtherObject *obj;

@end

@implementation MYObject

@synthesize obj = _obj;

@end
```

Here, calling `thing->obj` will yield nothing but errors since the member is allocated dynamically at runtime.

Also, as user @Peter Hosey points out, you can use `->` like C++'s `Friend` in methods like `copyWithZone` however, if you're not doing stuff like that, then stay away!

---

[EDIT]

Also, if you're trying to squeeze performance out of the object and you *know* what you're doing with that object or member then you could use `->` to skip the method-lookup's overhead.  Even then, however, you may just want to code those sections in C or C++ if performance is *that big of an issue.*

Oh, in addition, I don't think using `->` is thread-safe.  If your getter/setter uses `@synchronize` using `->` will bypass that the safe-guards.

Comment: Actually, I believe all instance variables (members) are `@protected` by default, rather than `@private`.

Comment: It turns out the code I see using this a lot is always exclusively using self->myvar. I know how thing->var would be "bad" but again, here we're only talking about self->myvar, which AFAIK is a more "descriptive" way of calling "myvar". I think one "nicer" option to differentiate ivars would be to use "_myvar" for ex., but I was never really sure how Apple meant this "not to be used by us" ;)

Comment: @StuFF mc, It's an artifact of having C being the underlying language of Objective-C.  It's also not thread-safe, which is probably the biggest reason to not use it.  No `(atomic)` or `@synchronized` applies when you use `->`.  They also left it in for the serious performance nuts out there that must just SQUEEZE life out of their app.  Notably, scientific and medical devices require that kind of speed.  But all in all, don't use it unless you *need* to and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`self->variable` is redundant, since you'll get the very same effect as referring to the ivar by itself.  Generally, the `->` operator comes in handy when the thing you want to access is an ivar in *another* instance, eg:

```
@implementation MyClass

- (void) beLikeThisOtherThing:(MyClass *) foo
{
someVariable = foo->someVariable;
}

@end
```